# Regex to match Zero and Comma

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex string that will capture the following text:

```
0, ,0,
```

I've tried a few variation of this but to no avail:

```
^[0,]+$

^[0,]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edited:
This will be used within another program that does regex pattern matching using Perl.  The program reads a file with a list of entries within it.  Using different profiles within the program I need to pick out entries that look like the following:

```
0, ,0,
```

These entries could also read like this:

```
1, ,0,
```

So the ideal regex I'm looking for would scan for "Does it start with a 1 or 0 immediatly followed by a comma then a space then a comma then number (0-9) and ending with a comma."

Further examples:

```
0, ,8,
1, ,5,
```

I hope that helps to clarify the request.

Thanks,

Comment: If the example is representative, your problem is requiring the match to be alone on a line. Try removing `^` and `$` for a start, then maybe refining your question if the result is still not to your liking.

Comment: You should provide **several** inputs with their expected output.

Comment: Which flavour of regex do you intend to use?

Comment: And do you really mean capture, or will just matching do?

Comment: As you can see from several answers, there is confusion as to whether the spaces in your example is part of the example. I have assumed that your title is descriptive, and that soaces are not part of the example; but you realny need to [edit] your question to make this clear and explicit.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:[0\s]+,)+
```

there is a space in your string, so you need \s to match it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't mention a particular regex implementation, so the answers you have received might not work for you. (Lesson: always specify the environment in which you plan to use this.)

In any reasonably modern regex variant,

```
[0,]+
```

matches a sequence of one or more characters. The character class `[abc]` matches a single character which is one of the enumerated characters inside the square brackets, and the quantifier `+` says to match the previous expression as many times as possible, but at least once.

Matching and capturing are separate concepts in some implementations. Perhaps you want to add parentheses around this regex to specify that you want to capture, not just match, the strings in the input which this regular expression describes (and in some implementations, you want to add a flag -commonly `g` - to say that you want all matches,not just the first).

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture spaces too with, for instance, `\s`:

```
^[0,\s]+$
```

`\s` will match all spaces characters and is the equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`.

See result in action here: https://regex101.com/r/g3faWA/1

---

You can also remove line delimiters (`^` and `$`) if you want to match the parts of the line that contains 0 and commas even if the line contains other characters. That would give:

```
[0,\s]+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `^(?:[0 ],)+$` or `^(?:[0\s],)+$`

**Details**:

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string
- `\s` matches any whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH2JVQ/2)